# AngularJS - update ng-repeat list in DOM instantly to allow animation

Tags: angularjs, dom, timeout, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I have a list to which I can add languages. When a language is added, there is an animation for maximum eye candy sexyness. The animation is triggered by a state change in `ng-show="lang.visible"` in the HTML. I have to first add the language to the language array, and THEN change the `visible` state to `true` for the animation to show.

The problem is, when I add the language to the array, it takes around 700 ms for the DOM to get updated, and then I change the state of `visible`. Those 700 ms make the page feel slow.

```
$scope.addTourDescLang = function(newLang) {
    newLang.visible = false;

    $scope.newClient.tours.languages.push(newLang);

    $timeout(function() {
        newLang.visible = true;
    }, 700 );
};
```

Here's the animation code:

```
<script>
app.animation('.slide-toggle', ['$animateCss', function($animateCss) {
    var lastId = 0;
    var _cache = {};

    function getId(el) {
        var id = el[0].getAttribute("data-slide-toggle");
        if (!id) {
            id = ++lastId;
            el[0].setAttribute("data-slide-toggle", id);
        }
        return id;
    }

    function getState(id) {
        var state = _cache[id];
        if (!state) {
            state = {};
            _cache[id] = state;
        }
        return state;
    }

    function generateRunner(closing, state, animator, element, doneFn) {
        return function() {
            state.animating = true;
            state.animator = animator;
            state.doneFn = doneFn;
            animator.start().finally(function() {
                if (closing && state.doneFn === doneFn) {
                    element[0].style.height = '';
                }
                element[0].style.height = 'auto';
                state.animating = false;
                state.animator = undefined;
                state.doneFn();
            });
        }
    }

    return {
        addClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
            if (className == 'ng-hide') {
                var state = getState(getId(element));
                var height = (state.animating && state.height) ? 
                    state.height : element[0].offsetHeight;

                var animator = $animateCss(element, {
                    from: {height: height + 'px'},
                    to: {height: '0px'}
                });
                if (animator) {
                    if (state.animating) {
                        state.doneFn = 
                          generateRunner(true, 
                                         state, 
                                         animator, 
                                         element, 
                                         doneFn);
                        return state.animator.end();
                    }
                    else {
                        state.height = height;
                        return generateRunner(true, 
                                              state, 
                                              animator, 
                                              element, 
                                              doneFn)();
                    }
                }
            }
            doneFn();
        },
        removeClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
            if (className == 'ng-hide') {
                var state = getState(getId(element));
                var height = (state.animating && state.height) ?  
                    state.height : element[0].offsetHeight;

                var animator = $animateCss(element, {
                    from: {height: '0px'},
                    to: {height: height + 'px'}
                });

                if (animator) {
                    if (state.animating) {
                        state.doneFn = generateRunner(false, 
                                                      state, 
                                                      animator, 
                                                      element, 
                                                      doneFn);
                        return state.animator.end();
                    }
                    else {
                        state.height = height;
                        return generateRunner(false, 
                                              state, 
                                              animator, 
                                              element, 
                                              doneFn)();
                    }
                }
            }
            doneFn();
        }
    };
}]);
```

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

    app.animation('.slide-toggle', ['$animateCss', function($animateCss) {
        return {
            addClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
                if (className == 'ng-hide') {
                    var animator = $animateCss(element, {                    
                        to: {height: '0px'}
                    });
                    if (animator) {
                        return animator.start().finally(function() {
                            element[0].style.height = '';
                            doneFn();
                        });
                    }
                }
                doneFn();
            },
            removeClass: function(element, className, doneFn) {
                if (className == 'ng-hide') {
                    var height = element[0].offsetHeight;
                    var animator = $animateCss(element, {
                        from: {height: '0px'},
                        to: {height: height + 'px'}
                    });
                    if (animator) {
                     return animator.start().finally(doneFn);
                    }
                }
                doneFn();
            }
        };
    }]);
})();
</script>
```

The CSS:

```
.slide-toggle {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.25s; 
}
```

The HTML:

```
<table class="table-list">
    <tbody ng-repeat="langAdded in newClient.tours.languages">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div ng-show="langAdded.added" class="table-list-content slide-toggle">
                    <div>
                        <img ng-src="/images/icons/flags/flag-{{ langAdded.code }}-30x20.png" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0 10px 0 20px;">
                        {{ langAdded.title }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div ng-show="langAdded.added" class="slide-toggle">
                    <md-button class="md-icon-button remove-icon-button" ng-click="removeTourDescLang(langAdded)" aria-label="Remove">
                        <md-icon md-svg-icon="/images/icons/svg/cross-close.svg"></md-icon>
                    </md-button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can this be done in a better way?
How can I update DOM instantly, and then directly after changing the `visible` state to `true`?

Comment: so you mean `$scope.newClient.tours.languages.push(newLang);` this takes around 700 ms?

Comment: Well, the operation doesn't actually take 700 ms. It's perceived as instant. I have to use timeout 700 ms before setting the `visible` state to `true` though in order to have the new item appear with an animation.

Comment: @MarcusEdensky Are you using `ng-repeat` to iterate through the array `$scope.newClient.tours.languages` ?

Comment: I didn't want to spam you guys with my code, but here it comes! Updated question.

Comment: @chinmayan Yes I am!

Comment: Try using `ng-repeat='langAdded in newClient.tours.languages track by $index'`, have you tried it?